# Как передать результат одной функции js в другую?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Существуют две функции, одна из которых записана в подгружаемом файле, другая - находится в конце html-файла:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
  </head>                                                
  <body>

  <p id="add_img">Download</p>

  </body>
</html>

<script>

  $("#add_img").click(function() {
    $("#image_loader").click();
  });   

</script>
```

Подгружаемая function.js (функция номер 1) в конце возвращает данные:

```
$(function(){

  var imageLoader = document.getElementById('image_loader');
  imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

  function handleImage(e){                                                       

    //some code

    return JSON.parse(response);
  }
});
```

Как возвращаемое значение передать в функцию 2?

**UPD**

Функция №1 является обработчиком изображения и возвращает массив, содержащий имя этого обработанного изображения на сервере и директорию, в которой оно находится. Возвращемые данные используются следующим образом:

```
var resp = JSON.parse(response);   
$("#product_img_preview").append('<li><a href="../../' + resp.uploaddir + '/' + resp.filename + '_card.jpeg"><img src="../../' + resp.uploaddir + '/' + resp.filename + '_prev_small.jpeg" /></a></li>');
```

Кроме того, добавленному с помощью функции №1 элементу `<li>...</li>` применяется обработчик наведения `$("#product_img_preview img").hover( function(){...} )`, в свою очередь находящийся в функции №2 и используемый только в этой функции.

В отдельный подгружаемый скрипт функция вынесена с целью избежать дублирования кода, поскольку сам код будет использоваться в дальнейшем на другой странице.

Comment: В функции номер 1 выполняется ajax?

Comment: да, post-запрос ajax-ом

Comment: в данном случае - никак, вы же обработчик вызываете, а не функцию

Comment: Давайте немного упростим и сделаем правильно. [Ваш код написанный правильно](https://jsfiddle.net/higimo/7bcL3jvn/), вы всё равно onready в подключаемом файле ждёте, так почему в шапке подключать? Быстрее аякс не сработает от этого. А теперь объясните, что вы хотите куда передать, потому что сейчас ничего не ясно из вашего синхронного потока мысли. JS — асинхронный. Объясните как используете полученное.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за ответ. Я оборачивал находящуюся в обработчике функцию в именованную функцию и вызывал её из функции №2. Работает, хотя в том случае были утечки памяти, которые я не смог побороть. Если все же вызывать в качестве именованной функции, а не обработчика, как можно получить результат в функции №2 ?

Comment: @higimo, разве у абзацев есть событие `change`?

Comment: @118_64, [вот просто отличнейший ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) на английском, но не уверен что его переводили на русский тут

Comment: @higimo, добавил в UPD описание того, что пытаюсь сделать с возвращаемым значением. Я не преследовал какую-то специальную цель, подключая в шапке, кроме как повторное использование кода. Возможно, я неправильно понял вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можете по получении данных в «функции 1», [триггерить](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) событие, в которое вложить данные.

А чтобы получить эти данные где угодно, в т.ч. в «функции 2», надо [назначить слушателя](http://api.jquery.com/on/) этого события.

```js
// здесь поймаем данные.
$(document).on('moeSobytie', function(e, data){
  $('#result').text( "Получены данные: " + data.title + ' ' + data.i );
});

// кнопка, запускающая всё
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  setTimeout( function_1, 2000);
});

function function_1() {
  // вызываем событие, приложив появившиеся данные:
  $(document).trigger('moeSobytie', {title:"название", i:15});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Запустить долгий процесс</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: ох :-D давно такого не видел :-D `moeSobytie`

Comment: Кстати, вы не видели тут перевода вопроса который я в комментариях добавлял? там как раз большинство способов получения значений из асинхронных функций описано. Но вот не помню было тут что-то подобное, обычно находится только какая-то часть

Comment: @Grundy не искал. Вопрос ТС не чисто про асинхронность, по-моему, его ещё чуть смущает, что часть кода прямо в теле документа, а часть подгружается из файла, и стоило бы разъяснить про очереденость событий при загрузке документа, может.

Comment: Именно то, что было нужно. Спасибо!